# How to understand this Python functional style code by Peter Norvig?

Tags: python, lambda

While reading Peter Norvig's Python IAQ, I came across this code snippet:

```
def _if(test):
    return lambda alternative: \
               lambda result: \
                   [delay(result), delay(alternative)][not not test]()
def delay(f):
    if callable(f): return f
    else: return lambda: f
fact = lambda n: _if (n <= 1) (1) (lambda: n * fact(n-1))
fact(100)
```

I searched this in the internet and this code appeared in several forums but it seems that those who commented on it all understand how it works.

I am quite new to functional programming concepts. I know that if test is evaluated to `True`, `delay(alternative)` will be selected. But in fact, if test is true, result is returned. This seems counter-intuitive to me.

Comment: IMHO not good Python style.

Comment: 5 `lambda`s in 7 lines? Is this an example of how not to code in Python?

Comment: It might be helpful to understand this if you convert each `lambda` to a named function (except the one in `delay`, which I think is pretty obvious). If that's not sufficient, try substituting through various results—e.g., manually evaluate `fact(2)`. (A better solution would be to go learn Haskell or ML, then figure out the obvious code this is incomprehensibly translated from, and then work out how it could be translated to Python and why Norvig chose this way… but I assume you want a slightly shorter-range solution.)

Comment: @AlexL: Python is not a functional language. It lacks some recursion optimizations common in truly functional languages and the default recursion dept is limited to ~1000 in cpython. So yes, I think converting the algorithm to a non-recursive form is more pythonic, but it is just my humble opinion.

Comment: I agree with what is said here - Python is not a functional language - while it draws some awesome stuff from functional languages, it's not a good idea to try and use a pure functional style, it's not optimal.

Comment: Nowhere in his IAQ Peter Norvig said it was a good idea :) (*«If u cn rd ths, u cn gt a jb in fncnl prg (if thr wr any)»*)

Comment: Thank you all for commenting. I know Python is not good for functional styles. I am just interested to know how this works. I learned a bit of Lisp to know about functional programming but I did not have much time practicing it. Most of the time I am stuck with Python or C (as I am an embedded developer).

Answer (score 5):

Let's see:

- `_if(True)` is called, and immediately returns a lambda with the `alternative` parameter
- The returned lambda is called with `alternative` set to `1` and returns the `result` lambda
- The `result` lambda is called with `result` set to `lambda: n * fact(n-1)`
- `not not True` evaluates to 1 (This example is from python 2.4 era!), which indexes the second list item, which is `delay(alternative)`
- `alternative` was set to `1` earlier
- `delay(1)` is called, which returns `lambda: 1`
- `lambda: 1` is called, it returns `1`.

TL/DR: `1` is the `alternative`.

Named functions version:

```
def _if(test):
    def then_closure(expr_if_true):
        def else_closure(expr_if_false):
            if test:
                delayed = delay(expr_if_true)
            else:
                delayed = delay(expr_if_false)
            return delayed()
        return else_closure
    return then_closure
```

Comment: +1, very nice… but I think it might be clearer if you started with `fact(2)` instead of `fact(1)`. I know the OP says he just wants to understand the `_if` `True` bit, but I suspect he actually needs one more step.

Comment: @Pavel Thank you. Your explanation really helped me understand it. It seems that i was tripped by the variable names. If I switch the variable names of `result` and `alternative`, the code starts to make sense to me. In that case, `_if` is used like `_if (test) result alternative`.

Answer (score 1):

Walk it through in reverse.

```
fact = lambda n: _if (n <= 1) (1) (lambda: n * fact(n-1))
fact(100)
```

The first function reduces to [ _if( 100 <= 1) ] and it selects between the two functions [ (1) ] and [ (lambda : n * fact(n-1)) ].  As already described True functions call the 2nd functions, False calls the first.  So the second function is called and the lambda is evaluated as:

```
lambda: 100 * fact(99)
```

Note that the delay function effective does nothing for this case.  The whole process starts over again with fact(99):

```
fact(99) =  lambda n: _if (99 <= 1) (1) (lambda: 99 * fact(98))
```

Again the _if function call is True and it triggers the 2nd function call which then calls another fact(98), and so forth.

The stack slowly builds up:

```
100 * fact(99) 
100 * 99 * fact(98)
100 * 99 * 98 * fact(97)
```

The special case is fact(1):

```
fact(1) = lambda n: _if (1 <= 1) (1) (lambda: 1 * fact(0))
```

since _if is now False the first function is passed to delay which converts it to a function  and calls it, returning 1 and allowing the stack to resolve. The multiplication occurs and the result is given (100!).

Comment: `_if` isn't given two parameters.

Comment: That's true, how does one refer to the result and alternative functions?

Comment: `_if (n <= 1)` returns a function, which is passed `1` as a parameter, and then that returns a function which is passed `lambda: n * fact(n-1)`?

Comment: Absolutely, this has been reflected in my post.